# How to display "." in Yajra Datatable Laravel infyom

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

I am working on Laravel Infyom generator. Every thing is working perfectly for me. My requirement is display **"."** , in header of datatable.

```
private function getColumns()
```

is responsible for display headers but when i use **"Dept.No"** then it is display in datatbale "Dept No". I want "." also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'id'         => ['title' => 'Código'],
            'nome'       => ['title' => 'Nome do Produto'],
            'grupo'      => ['title' => 'Grupo'],
            'estoque'    => ['title' => 'Estoque'],
            'preco'      => ['title' => 'Preço de Venda'],
            'custo'      => ['title' => 'Preço de Custo'],
            'ativo'      => ['title' => 'Ativo?'],
            'created_at' => ['title' => 'Dt. Cadastro']
        ];
}
```